# PHP Match foreach values with an multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following array:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [year] => 1
                [month] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [month] => 2
                                [value] => 600
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [month] => 3
                                [value] => 600
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [month] => 4
                                [value] => 600
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [year] => 5
                [month] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [month] => 6
                                [value] => 80
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [month] => 7
                                [value] => 90
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [month] => 8
                                [value] => 100
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

and also i have a foreach for 10 years that also foreach for every month. Something like this:

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $year) {
     foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
            $value = $month;
     }
}
```

Now the problem is how i can match the array with the foreach to change the $value if the $year and $month it's in the array, and if the year/month combination it's on the array the $value value needs to be the one from the that month in array.

Comment: Could you rephrase what you are trying to do? I don't think I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having written the below, it is worth mentioning that the whole exercise seems a little pointless.
As you are iterating through every month in a ten year period, it would be much simpler to iterate the data and check if the year matches (because no month in that year can logically be outside the range 1-12), rather than iterate through 120 months to see if the data contains a value for that month:

```
foreach($data as $year_data) {
    if(in_array($year_data['year'], range(1,10)){
        foreach($year['month'] as $month) {
            echo = $month['value'];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Well its not clear what you want to do with the data, but to get to it you will need to iterate the array with nested foreach loops:

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $year) {
    foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
         //iterate the array to find the correct element
         $foundValue = false;
         foreach($data as $year_data){
            if($year_data['year']==$year){
                foreach($year_data['month'] as $month_data){
                    if($month_data['month']==$month){
                        //do something with the data
                        $foundValue = $month_data['value'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo ($foundValue) ?: $defaultValue;
    }
}
```

If you could restructure the data array to be indexed by year and month, eg:

```
$data = array(
      'year_1'=>array(
                      'month_2'=>600,
                      'month_3'=>600,
                      'month_4'=>600
                     ),
      'year_5'=>array(
                      'month_6'=>80,
                      'month_7'=>90,
                      'month_8'=>100
                     ),
     );
```

Then you could access the data alot easier:

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $year) {
    foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
         //access value directly via keys:
         if(isset($data['year_'.$year]['month_'.$month];)){
             echo $data['year_'.$year]['month_'.$month];
         }else{
             echo $defaultValue;
         }
    }
}
```

Even if you cant alter how the data is created, you could still create a new array with the above structure:

```
$newData = array();

foreach($data as $year_data){
    $year = 'year_'.$year_data['year'];
    $months = array();
    foreach($year_data['month'] as $month_data){
        $months['month_'.$month_data['month']]=$month_data['value'];
    }
    $newData[$year]=$months;
}
```

Then you can use `$newData` in place of `$data` in the simplified example above.

Comment: Steve and @Dr Casper Black, thanks for your very complete answer, this works but i also need to show the default month value.` if($month_data['month']==$month){
                        echo $month_data['value'];
                    }` i've tried something like `                    if($month_data['month']==$month){
                        echo $month_data['value'];
                    }else{echo $default_month_value;}` but this way every months will be repeated by the number of month in that array.

Comment: @AlexandruBurdulea Well you need to save the value outside the inner loops, then after those loops, if the value there, echo it, else echo default. I dont know what the default should be so i used `$defaultValue` in my edited answer

Comment: @AlexandruBurdulea Also added break to avoid unnecessary loops if you are using the 1st example (hint - you shouldnt be, restructuring once and using the second one is more efficient)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly for what i was looking. Works exactly how i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but this may help you. This will go trough your array of year/month, check if year corresponds, if yes, it will check if month matches, if yes show values.

The year and month range will match all your data-array entries.

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $year) {
     foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
        foreach($ar as $row){
            if ($row['year'] == $year){
                foreach($row['month'] as $rowMonth){
                    if($rowMonth['month'] == $month){
                        echo "match: Y:".$row['year']." - m:".$rowMonth['month']." -> ". $rowMonth['value']."<br>"; 
                    }

                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

`$year_month = array(
                array(
                    'year' => 1,
                    'month'  => array(
                        array('month'  => 2, 'value'  => 600),
                        array('month'  => 3, 'value'  => 600),
                        array('month'  => 4, 'value'  => 600)
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'year'  => 5,
                    'month'  => array(
                        array('month'  => 6, 'value'  => 80),
                        array('month'  => 7, 'value'  => 90),
                        array('month'  => 8, 'value'  => 100)
                    )
                )
            );`

`foreach($year_month as $year) {
    foreach($year['month'] as $month) {
        $value = $month['value'];
        echo $value.'<br/>';
    }
}`

Output:

`600
600
600
80
90
100`